# Remove or hide toolbar panel in Jpanel

Tags: java, jpanel, graphics2d

When I work with Jpanel, I see that while Y is below 50 I don`t see objects, as they are hidden under top panel. I need a way to hide top panel or make it possible to not to add 50 to Y each time. In this example, top of the circle is hidden:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class Draw extends JFrame{

    public static int Framesize=1000;

    public static void main(String []args){
        Draw s=new Draw();
        s.setVisible(true);


    }

    public Draw(){
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        setSize(Framesize,Framesize);

        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i=0;i<=1000;i+=50) {
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(i, 0, i, Framesize));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, i, Framesize, i));

        }
        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Float(0,0,200,200));
        g2.drawString("Test", 100, 150);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to **use** the JPanel variable you've created (because it's not a good practice to paint directly in the JFrame as you were doing just because It can cause the problem you were having). Here is an example of the panel class:

```
class panel extends JPanel{

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 50) {
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(i, 0, i, Draw.Framesize));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, i, Draw.Framesize, i));

    }
    g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 200, 200));
    g2.drawString("Test", 100, 150);
}
```

}

Then add the panel class to the frame constructor
`panel panel = new panel();
 add(panel);`

Finally remove the paint function from the main frame (because you have already defined it in the panel class).

However, there is no point in removing the upside bar (because, objects below 50 in Y axis will appear).

But if for some reason you still want to remove the upside bar then, in order to remove it you have to define in the constructor: `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
 setUndecorated(true);`

Finally remove the paint function from the main frame (because you have already defined it in the panel class).